# How to set / appear value date in input text using Datebox

Tags: javascript, php, html, calendar, datebox

I have been looking for Datebox how to keep a value in input text without changing the default current date in calendar.
The value in input text I called from database and it may different.

I want:
- Disable previous date/month/year (let say 2015-09-14) but keep enabling for current month or next 2 months in calendar.
- If the value in input text is 2015-09-14, the selected date value in calendar still on the current date / month.

Scripts I have tried so far:

[image]

JavaScript:

[image]

Output:

[image: already disabled but empty value in input text]
[image: enable current month but empty value in input text]

Expected:

[image: no empty value, still disable]
[image: no empty value, selected date based on current date/month]

Comment: Have you tried the `setValue` method - `$('#datebox').datebox('setValue', '2015-09-14').datebox('calendar')...` https://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/datebox.php

Comment: Yes, I have but the result is not 2015-09-14 but current date or today.

Comment: is your value in a php variable that you can set, ie `$('#datebox').datebox('setValue', '<?php echo $mySpecialDate; ?>').datebox('calendar')...`

Comment: You shouldn't include images of your code. Directly write it

Comment: It still appears by current date. If it does not use the validator on JS, it appears by the previous date and no problem but did not disable and selected by previous date itself.

Comment: @Gibolt I had tried before post, got something error with some codes I wrote but no idea which got the error.